# Constant camera grabbing with OpenCV & Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, camera, multiprocessing

I'm after constantly reading images from an OpenCV camera in Python and reading from the main program the latest image. This is needed because of problematic HW.

After messing around with threads and getting a very low efficiency (duh!), I'd like to switch to multiprocessing.

Here's the threading version:

```
class WebcamStream:
    # initialization method
    def __init__(self, stream_id=0):
        self.stream_id = stream_id  # default is 0 for main camera

        # opening video capture stream
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(self.stream_id)
        self.camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 3840)
        self.camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 2880)

        if self.camera.isOpened() is False:
            print("[Exiting]: Error accessing webcam stream.")
            exit(0)

        # reading a single frame from camera stream for initializing
        _, self.frame = self.camera.read()

        # self.stopped is initialized to False
        self.stopped = True

        # thread instantiation
        self.t = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.t.daemon = True  # daemon threads run in background

    # method to start thread
    def start(self):
        self.stopped = False
        self.t.start()

    # method passed to thread to read next available frame
    def update(self):
        while True:
            if self.stopped is True:
                break
            _, self.frame = self.camera.read()
        self.camera.release()

    # method to return latest read frame
    def read(self):
        return self.frame

    # method to stop reading frames
    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True
```

And -

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_camera_stream = WebcamStream(stream_id=0)
    main_camera_stream.start()
    frame = main_camera_stream.read()
```

Can someone please help me translate this to multiprocess land ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written several solutions to similar problems, but it's been a little while so here we go:

I would use `shared_memory` as a buffer to read frames into, which can then be read by another process. My first inclination is to initialize the camera and read frames in the child process, because that seems like it would be a "set it and forget it" kind of thing.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

def produce_frames(q):
    #get the first frame to calculate size of buffer
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    success, frame = cap.read()
    shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=frame.nbytes)
    framebuffer = np.ndarray(frame.shape, frame.dtype, buffer=shm.buf) #could also maybe use array.array instead of numpy, but I'm familiar with numpy
    framebuffer[:] = frame #in case you need to send the first frame to the main process
    q.put(shm) #send the buffer back to main
    q.put(frame.shape) #send the array details
    q.put(frame.dtype)
    try:
        while True:
            cap.read(framebuffer)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        shm.close() #call this in all processes where the shm exists
        shm.unlink() #call from only one process

def consume_frames(q):
    shm = q.get() #get the shared buffer
    shape = q.get()
    dtype = q.get()
    framebuffer = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=shm.buf) #reconstruct the array
    try:
        while True:
            cv2.imshow("window title", framebuffer)
            cv2.waitKey(100)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        shm.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    producer = Process(target=produce_frames, args=(q,))
    producer.start()
    consume_frames(q)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Would it be rude to ask what of all this is the absolute necessary?

Comment: It could definitely be trimmed down.. I copy-pasted some of it from other answers, and for a single-use instance, an entire class is rarely necessary.

Comment: @Gabe I trimmed down the example closer to the minimum necessary.  I got a little carried away earlier :|

Comment: Thank you so much, @Aaron. Are the three lines of the second function right?

Comment: @Gabe which three lines are you referring to? The code works with a direct copy paste for me...

Comment: shape = q.get()
    dtype = q.get()

Comment: @Gabe those correspond to the `q.put()` lines in the `produce_frames` frunction to send the information necessary to reconstruct the array back to the main process as well as the buffer itself.

Comment: Beautiful. Appreciated

Comment: when adding
     cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 3840)
     cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 2880)
The process throws out:

shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=frame.nbytes)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nbytes'

Comment: @Gabe the camera failed to initialize, so `frame` was `None`. I'd bet `success` is `False` also. That was one of the things I got rid of by trimming down the code was error checking... Make sure no other instances of the program are still running, and have exclusive access to the camera (or other programs that may try to grab the camera)

Comment: done all you said and still... Can you check on your side please?

Comment: @Gabe There is only one possible issue here: `cap.read()` failed. That will depend on your camera setup. It works fine for me.

Comment: You're right, @Aaron. It was the camera. Last nudge, please: would you suggest a viable way to get the image back to the Main module?

Comment: @Gabe the first image? assign it back to the buffer before going on with the loop: `framebuffer[:] = frame`

Comment: I'd appreciate a more elaborate explanation. Where precisely? Would you please change your answer? I'd like the process to grab images always but return the frame to the Main module on demand.

Comment: Would you please assist, @Aaron ?

Comment: Whenever data is written to the framebuffer by the child process it is instantly available to the main process, because the two framebuffer arrays point to the same region of shared system memory. My example already is using the data in the main process, by calling `cv2.imshow` from the main process. Without any mutex protection, there is nothing to prevent main from reading the data while the child is halfway through a write.

Comment: I see, @Aaron. The thing is that in your example the entire reading is done in a loop and the shm.close line comes after it. I don't know how to make this into a "give me just one frame on demand" thing.