# Constant camera grabbing with OpenCV & Python multiprocessing - Follow up

Tags: python, opencv, camera, multiprocessing, shared-memory

This is a followup on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72469003/constant-camera-grabbing-with-opencv-python-multiprocessing) where @Aaron helped quite a lot.

Context:
OpenCV, Python, a USB Webcam and multiprocessing - Grabbing all the time from the camera on a subprocess and **returning a single frame upon request** to the main process.
@Aaron did most of the heavylifting, of not all :). What I am missing is how to turn this into a process that gets a single frame upon request.

Help Please?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

def produce_frames(q):
    #get the first frame to calculate size of buffer
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    success, frame = cap.read()
    shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=frame.nbytes)
    framebuffer = np.ndarray(frame.shape, frame.dtype, buffer=shm.buf) #could also maybe use array.array instead of numpy, but I'm familiar with numpy
    framebuffer[:] = frame #in case you need to send the first frame to the main process
    q.put(shm) #send the buffer back to main
    q.put(frame.shape) #send the array details
    q.put(frame.dtype)
    try:
        while True:
            cap.read(framebuffer)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        shm.close() #call this in all processes where the shm exists
        shm.unlink() #call this in at least one process

def consume_frames(q):
    shm = q.get() #get the shared buffer
    shape = q.get()
    dtype = q.get()
    framebuffer = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=shm.buf) #reconstruct the array
    try:
        while True:
            cv2.imshow("window title", framebuffer)
            cv2.waitKey(100)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        shm.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    producer = Process(target=produce_frames, args=(q,))
    producer.start()
    consume_frames(q)
```

Comment: honestly there's no need to do that in a separate process (and consequently no need for shm). reading from a camera is perfectly fine to do from a thread. it doesn't cost any cpu to wait for the next frame, and python's multithreading isn't as incompetent as everyone loves to portray it (they have no clue). here's something I over-engineered a while ago: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz. I beg to differ. It WOULD be fine if it wasn't a "White (True)" operation which hogs the core.

Comment: I beg to differ. you misunderstood what I said. I'm saying multiprocessing is overkill, just use threads. -- a `while True:` on its own does nothing but loop. if the loop body blocks on a `read()` call (which only unblocks 30 or 60 or so times a second, when there's data from the camera), the entire thread is blocked and not scheduled at all (now you'd have to know that a thread that isn't scheduled, isn't using cpu cycles). serial code _does_ prevent whatever instructions come *after* to run before the *current* instruction is done, which is good and proper. but *nobody* suggested that.

Comment: and perhaps check out what I linked to... don't be dismissive while asking others for help.

Comment: Hi. Not dismissive at all. Actually very grateful. Will look deeper into the link. Thank you