# How can I continuously loop over a video which is being constantly updated?

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing, video-processing

My goal is to be able to continuously loop video1.mp4, but update the video as soon as my video generator function generates a new video1. I have tried various approaches involving creating the new video under the name video2.mp4, then checking to see if video2 exists and then renaming video2 to video1 etc but with no luck. My current function technically does the job although pauses and floods my terminal with error messages while the new video1 is being written:

```
def video_player():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video1.mp4')

    while  True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        else:
            cap.release()
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video1.mp4')
            ret, frame = cap.read()
```

I am using multiprocessing to simultaneously run the video generator function and this video_player() function. How can I constantly play the video on loop and seamlessly swap to the most recent generated video whenever it is generated?

Comment: Do you need to save the video to disk? can you just write frames to `multiprocessing.shared_memory` instead and have the reader access the frames directly? I have a few answers in my back catalog on how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried writing the new video to a different file, and in your loop, checking if a new video file with a higher number exists?

Comment: @Aaron, no the videos do not need to be saved to disk so perhaps this could work. If you could direct me to any answers in your back catalog that may be relevant that would be incredibly helpful, thanks.

Comment: @NickODell, yes I have tried a few variations of this approach. I was checking to see if a new video2 existed and then trying to replace video 1 with the new one but couldn't get this to work after a few hours of trying different implementations. I'm sure a better python programmer could find a solution this way, so I'd love to know if you have an idea of exactly how to go about this.

Comment: @user20431 What happens if you check if video2 exists and then play video2 (**no renaming** to video1, since video1 cannot be renamed whilst in use/playing and secondly you can't have two files called video1 in same folder. You might need to stop & delete video1 before renaming another file as video1...  Or just load (when ready) as video2 then video3 etc etc...

Comment: @user20431 [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72470466/3220135) one... in this instance there's no protection against reading the frame while it's being written, which could cause screen tearing (frame updates in the middle of displaying), but you could get more complicated with multiple buffers, and locks to avoid this.