# Python multiprocessing queue using a lot of resources with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing, queue

I am using multiprocessing to get frames of a video using Opencv in python.

My class looks like this :-

```
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class StreamVideos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image_data = Queue()

    def start_proces(self):
        p = Process(target=self.echo)
        p.start()

    def echo(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videoplayback.mp4')
        while cap.isOpened():
            ret,frame = cap.read()
            self.image_data.put(frame)
            # print("frame")
```

I start the process "echo" using :-

```
p = Process(target=self.echo)
p.start()
```

the echo function looks like this :-

```
def echo(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videoplayback.mp4')
        while cap.isOpened():
            ret,frame = cap.read()
            self.image_data.put(frame)
```

in which i am using queue where i put these frames

```
self.image_data.put(frame)
```

and then in another process I start reviving these frames

```
    self.obj = StreamVideos()


    def start_process(self):
        self.obj.start_proces()
        p = Process(target=self.stream_videos)
        p.start()



    def stream_videos(self):
        while True:
            self.img = self.obj.image_data.get()
            print(self.img)
```

but as soon as I start putting frames to queue, the ram gets filled very quickly and the system gets stuck. The video I am using is just 25 fps and 39mb in size, so it does not make any sense.

One thing I noticed is that the "echo" process is putting a lot of frames in the queue before the "stream_videos" process retrives it.

What could be the root of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Expectations: -

1. Able to retrieve the frames continuosly.

Tried :-

1. Not putting frames in queue, in which case the ram is not filled.

Comment: "just ... 39mb in size" -- compressed with MPEG4, which can achieve compression ratios well over 100:1. And you're decompressing them as fast as possible, and dumping the decoded raw frames into a queue. Does that make sense now? | Just set the `maxsize` of the queue to something reasonable. When it gets full, you just wait for the consumer to catch up.

Comment: Additionally, you should always check if `ret` (success) is true for each frame.

Comment: Using a queue is going to incur quite a lot of overhead for transferring frames. I have used `shared_memory` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72470466/3220135 You may need several buffers, and some locks if you want to never drop frames.

Comment: Frankly using multiple processes for this seems like an overkill (and a lot of unneeded complexity). IIRC both OpenCV and numpy release the GIL in any complex enough function, so plain multithreading scales well enough. And you get the benefit of single memory space, so there's barely any overhead using a queue.

Comment: I am replying to this really late , It is the first time i am using this comment section so i don't know how to tell who here told me the solution but thanks a lot i changed my video file from mp4 to avi and my issue was resolved

Answer (score 1):

The following is a general purpose single producer/multiple consumer implementation. The producer (class `StreamVideos`) creates a shared memory array whose size is the number of bytes in the video frame. One or more consumers (you specify the number of consumers to `StreamVideos`) can then call `StreamVideos.get_next_frame()` to retrieve the next frame. This method converts the shared array back into a `numpy` array for subsequent processing. The producer will only read the next frame into the shared array after all consumers have called `get_next_frame`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import cv2

class StreamVideos:
    def __init__(self, path, n_consumers):
        """
        path is the path to the video:
        n_consumers is the number of tasks to which we will be sreaming this.
        """
        self._path = path

        self._event = multiprocessing.Event()

        self._barrier = multiprocessing.Barrier(n_consumers + 1, self._reset_event)

        # Discover how large a framesize is by getting the first frame
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self._path)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            self._shape = frame.shape
            frame_size = self._shape[0] * self._shape[1] * self._shape[2]
            self._arr = multiprocessing.RawArray(ctypes.c_ubyte, frame_size)
        else:
            self._arr = None
        cap.release()

    def _reset_event(self):
        self._event.clear()

    def start_streaming(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self._path)

        while True:
            self._barrier.wait()
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                # No more readable frames:
                break

            # Store frame into shared array:
            temp = np.frombuffer(self._arr, dtype=frame.dtype)
            temp[:] = frame.flatten(order='C')

            self._event.set()

        cap.release()
        self._arr = None
        self._event.set()

    def get_next_frame(self):
        # Tell producer that this consumer is through with the previous frame:
        self._barrier.wait()
        # Wait for next frame to be read by the producer:
        self._event.wait()
        if self._arr is None:
            return None

        # Return shared array as a numpy array:
        return np.ctypeslib.as_array(self._arr).reshape(self._shape)

def consumer(producer, id):
    frame_name = f'Frame - {id}'
    while True:
        frame = producer.get_next_frame()
        if frame is None:
            break
        cv2.imshow(frame_name, frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def main():
    producer = StreamVideos('videoplayback.mp4', 2)

    consumer1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer, args=(producer, 1))
    consumer1.start()
    consumer2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer, args=(producer, 2))
    consumer2.start()

    """
    # Run as a child process:
    producer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer.start_streaming)
    producer_process.start()
    producer_process.join()
    """
    # Run in main process:
    producer.start_streaming()

    consumer1.join()
    consumer2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```